# rendered attribute on RichFaces spacer tag

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm reading the documentation for the "spacer" tag at [JBoss](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/rich/spacer.html) . One of the attributes for this tag is "rendered". What does that mean? It's a space... What is the difference between a rendered space and an unrendered space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Space is used as visual delimiter between 2 components. If one of components is not rendered, then usually space before it not needed. It means spacer can be rendered with the same rendering condition as the component. Then spacer and component will appear and disappear together based on result of rendering condition.